# Access QNX Filesystem in Windows

Tags: linux, filesystems, qnx, oberon

I have a QNX partition in a CF card, running on a SBC. How do I access the filesystem in Windows, using something like an Explorer interface?

The filesystem is in QNX Oberon. I've also had QNX Momentics IDE but that is no help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some googling it looks like you can get the [WinQFile utility](http://www.openqnx.com/node/45)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any support for it. Any alternatives?

Comment: Nvm, mods are not easily pleased.